# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, xml

I have a working on app on a device with API 22, But when I tried to install the same app on device with API 19 (Xiomi device) I get below error;

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Here is the activity_login.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_login" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is content_login.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_login" tools:context=".LoginActivity">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="username"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etUsername"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="password"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etUsername" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Mobile Number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etMobile"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login"
            android:id="@+id/bLogin"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etPassword" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.myschool"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

}
```

Here is the error Log:

```
03-14 18:55:06.162 5253-5253/com.test.myschool E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 18:55:06.162 5253-5253/com.test.myschool E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.test.myschool, PID: 5253
03-14 18:55:06.162 5253-5253/com.test.myschool E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.myschool/com.test.myschool.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
03-14 18:55:06.162 5253-5253/com.test.myschool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2382)
03-14 18:55:06.162 5253-5253/com.test.myschool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
03-14 18:55:06.162 5253-5253/com.test.myschool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154)
03-14 18:55:06.162 5253-5253/com.test.myschool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
03-14 18:55:06.162 5253-5253/com.test.myschool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
03-14 18:55:06.162 5253-5253/com.test.myschool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
03-14 18:55:06.162 5253-5253/com.test.myschool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
03-14 18:55:06.162 5253-5253/com.test.myschool E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 18:55:06.162 5253-5253/com.test.myschool E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-14 18:55:06.162 5253-5253/com.test.myschool E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:835)
03-14 18:55:06.162 5253-5253/com.test.myschool E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
03-14 18:55:06.162 5253-5253/com.test.myschool E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: try removing popup theme from toolbar

Comment: is this the entire log??

Comment: @VivekMishra I tried with  deleting app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" But no change in behaviour. Still Exception

Comment: @Raghunandan I have updated entire Exception

Comment: then try removing background color also from toolbar as your error is in toolbar

Comment: @VivekMishra I have removed entire android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout Its working But I lost App Bar, there is something wrong here. Do you think I need to download any thing from AndroidSDK\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs ?

Comment: The problem I think is with attr attribute that you are giving for colors and dimensions. Try giving them directly and don't remove complete AppBar